# TF Lite shows only zeros on prediction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm building a model in Tensorflow 2.10 for classification problem. Model on PC works fine but converted model to TF Lite shows only zeros on prediction list. Model was tested on Android 13 using flutter.

I want to repair the model but I don't see any error that would cause this result.

Code in Dart looks this:

```
final String column_order =
List ColumnOrderData = await json.decode(column_order);
var beacons = data[0]['beacons'];
var exampleData = List<double>.filled(234, 0);
for (var i = 0; i < beacons.length; i++) {
var beaconName = beacons[i]['beaconName'];
double beaconRssiValue = beacons[i]['rssi'].toDouble();
if (beaconRssiValue != 127) {
beaconRssiValue = (beaconRssiValue * (-1)) / 105;
int index =
ColumnOrderData.indexWhere((element) => element == beaconName);
exampleData[index] = beaconRssiValue;
     }
   }
var output = List<double>.filled(4, 0);
final interpreter =
await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/model.tflite');
interpreter.run([exampleData], output.reshape([1, 4]));
```

This is part of model:

```
visible = Input(shape=(234,))
hidden1 = Dense(250, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(visible)
drp1 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden1)
norm1 = BatchNormalization()(drp1)
hidden2 = Dense(125, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(norm1)
drp2 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden2)
norm2 = BatchNormalization()(drp2)
hidden3 = Dense(80, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(norm2)
drp3 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden3)
norm3 = BatchNormalization()(drp3)
hidden4 = Dense(40, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(norm3)
drp4 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden4)
norm4 = BatchNormalization()(drp4)
out_reg = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(norm4)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=[out_reg])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
```

Code to convert in Pyton:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'saved_models\\')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved_models\\')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Input look like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8952380952380953, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9523809523809523, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8952380952380953, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9238095238095239, 0.9428571428571428, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And output like this:

`[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trail I found out that shape must be reshaped when variable is initialized `var output = List.filled(4, 0).reshape([1, 4]);`